# Interruptable Sleep?

Tags: python, multithreading, events, timer, busy-waiting

I am currently building a python app which should trigger functions at given timestamps entered by the user (not entered in chronological order).
I ran into a problem because I don't want my program to be busy-waiting checking if a new timestamp has been entered that must be added to the timer queue but also not creating a whole bunch of threads for every time a new timestamp is creating with its single purpose waiting for that timestamp.
What I thought of is putting it all together in one thread and doing something like an interruptable sleep, but I can't think of another way besides this:

```
while timer_not_depleted:
      sleep(1)
      if something_happened:
          break
```

which is essentially busy-waiting.
So any suggestions on realizing an interruptable sleep?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition of using threads is correct. The following master-worker construction can work:

- The master thread spawns a worker thread that waits for "jobs";
- The two threads share a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) - whenever a new job needs to be scheduled, the master thread [`put`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put)s a job specification into the queue;
- Meanwhile, the worker thread does the following:

  - Maintain a separate list of future jobs to run and keep track of how long to keep sleeping until the next job runs;
  - Continue listening to new jobs by calling [`Queue.get(block=True, timeout=<time-to-next-job>)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get);
  - In this case, if no new jobs are scheduled until the timeout, `Queue.get` will raise `Empty` exception - and at this point the worker thread should run the scheduled function and get back to polling. If a new job *is* scheduled in the meantime, `Queue.get` returns the new job, such that you can update the `timeout` value and then get back to waiting.

Comment: After some coding this looks very promising, so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select).

Call it with a timeout equal to the delay to the nearest event ([heap queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) is a good data structure to maintain a queue of future timestamps) and provide a socket (as an item in the `rlist` arg), where your program listens on for updates from the user.

The `select` call returns when the socket has incoming data or when the timeout has occurred.